# why data is not shown in adpaters android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

In RecordAdpater class i use logs for data showing. in RecordModel class data is set from Activity Main class and its working.but in RecordAdpater class when i want to get that data nothing is showing there.
everything is good at prospective.i don't know why data is not showing there.even log value is not null or 0. nothing is showing there why.why and why?
please help me, and thanks in advance.

**Main Activity**
package com.example.coronatasbeeh;

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.VibrationEffect;
import android.os.Vibrator;


import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textViewResult, textViewLapCounter;
    ImageButton btnReset, btnMinus;
    int count = 0;
    int lapCount = 0;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Model> main_List;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    Boolean sound,vibration,minusBtn;
     int countLimit;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //For custom toolbar

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //For Bottom Nav.


        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationBar);
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home_bottomNav);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.home_bottomNav:
                        return true;
                    case R.id.record_bottomNav:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RecordActivity.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.setting_bottomNav:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingActivity.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });    
        textViewResult = findViewById(R.id.textViewCount);
        textViewLapCounter = findViewById(R.id.textViewLapCounter);
        btnReset = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
        btnMinus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnMinus);

        final Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        main_List = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_dua);
        // for Recyler Dua container layout Style + add Data in it.
        main_List.add(new Model("DUA#01", "الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ الَّذِي عَافَانِي مِمَّا ابْتَلَاكَ بِهِ وَفَضَّلَنِي عَلَى كَثِيرٍ مِمَّنْ خَلَقَ تَفْضِيلً"));
        adapter = new DuaAdapter(main_List, getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        // for sound

        final MediaPlayer addSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.add_sound);
        final MediaPlayer minusSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.minus_sound);

        SharedPreferences loadSettingPref = getSharedPreferences("com.example.coronatasbeeh.mySetting", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        countLimit = loadSettingPref.getInt("lapLimit", 0);
     sound=  loadSettingPref.getBoolean("soundSetting", true);
     vibration =   loadSettingPref.getBoolean("vibrateSetting", true);
     minusBtn = loadSettingPref.getBoolean("minusSetting", true);

     if (minusBtn==false){
         btnMinus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     }


        //load save data, when app start:
        SharedPreferences myCount = getSharedPreferences("myTotalCount", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        count = myCount.getInt("count", 0);
        lapCount = myCount.getInt("lap", 0);
        textViewResult.setText("" + count);
        textViewLapCounter.setText("" + lapCount);
        textViewResult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count += 1;
                if (vibration==true){
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(200, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
                } else {
                    //deprecated in API 26
                    vibrator.vibrate(200);
                }}
                textViewResult.setText("" + count);
                if (sound==true) {
                    addSound.start();
                }
                if (count > 0) {
                    if (count == countLimit)

                    {

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                            vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
                        } else {
                            //deprecated in API 26
                            vibrator.vibrate(500);
                        }
                        lapCount++;
                        textViewLapCounter.setText("" + lapCount);
                    }
                    if (count > countLimit) {

                        textViewResult.setText("1");
                        count = 1;
                    }
                }

                SharedPreferences myCount = getSharedPreferences("myTotalCount", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myCount.edit();
                editor.putInt("count", count);
                editor.putInt("lap", lapCount);
                editor.commit();

            }
        });
/*        btnReset*/
        btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (count == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your counter is already 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    if (sound==true){
                    minusSound.start();}
                    count -= 1;
                    textViewResult.setText("" + count);
                    Log.i("test", "onClick: "+count);
                }


                SharedPreferences myCount = getSharedPreferences("myTotalCount", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myCount.edit();
                editor.putInt("count", count);
                editor.commit();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id==R.id.shareApp){

            if (count!=0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                String url = "https://www.google.com/";
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My Counter number is " + textViewResult.getText().toString() + " and my lap is " + lapCount + "\n  " + url);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "My Counter Details"));
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You don't have enough data for sharing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
        if (id==R.id.save) {
            if (textViewResult.getText().toString().equals("0")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You don't have enough data for saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.save_dialog, null);
                final Button btn_Save = mView.findViewById(R.id.btnSaveofSaveDialog);
                final Button btn_Cancel = mView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelSaveDialog);
                final EditText editTextCounterTitle = mView.findViewById(R.id.editTextCounterTitle);
                //  String ed_text = editTextLapLimit.getText().toString().trim();
                alert.setView(mView);
                final AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
                alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

                alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                btn_Cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                btn_Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try {
                            if (editTextCounterTitle.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                                editTextCounterTitle.setError("please enter title for save");

                            }
                            else {
```

// here i send data fro RecordModel Class..

```
                                RecordModel recordModel =  new RecordModel();
                                int c,lap,totalC;
                                c =Integer.parseInt(textViewResult
                                        .getText().toString());
                                lap = Integer.parseInt(textViewLapCounter.
                                        getText().toString());
                                totalC = lap*countLimit+c;
                                recordModel.setRecordCount(c);
                                recordModel.setRecordLap(lap);
                                recordModel.setRecordLimit(countLimit);
                                recordModel.setRecordTotalCount(totalC);
                                Log.i("totalC", "onClick: "+totalC);
                                recordModel.setRecordTitle(editTextCounterTitle.getText().toString());
                                Log.i("setTitle", "onClick: "+editTextCounterTitle.getText().toString());
                                Log.i("getTotalRC", "onClick: "+recordModel.getRecordTotalCount());
                                alertDialog.dismiss();
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }


    public void showResetDialogBox(View view) {
        final MediaPlayer restSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.reset_sound);
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.reset_alert_dialog, null);
        Button btn_Reset = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnResetAlertDialog);
        Button btn_Cancel = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelAlertDialog);
        alert.setView(mView);
        final  AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        btn_Cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


            btn_Reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (count == 0) {
                        textViewResult.setText("0");
                        textViewLapCounter.setText("0");
                        lapCount = 0;
                    } else {
                        count = 0;
                        lapCount = 0;
                        restSound.start();
                        textViewResult.setText("" + count);
                        textViewLapCounter.setText("" + count);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Reset successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    alertDialog.dismiss();


                    SharedPreferences myCount = getSharedPreferences("myTotalCount", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myCount.edit();
                    editor.putInt("count", count);
                    editor.putInt("lap", lapCount);
                    editor.commit();

                }

            });


        alertDialog.show();

    }


}
```

**RecordModel class.**

```
package com.example.coronatasbeeh;

public class RecordModel {
    String recordTitle;
    int recordCount;
    int recordLap;
    int recordLimit;
    int recordTotalCount;

    public RecordModel() {
    }

    public RecordModel(String recordTitle, int recordCount, int recordLap, int recordLimit, int recordTotalCount) {
        this.recordTitle = recordTitle;
        this.recordCount = recordCount;
        this.recordLap = recordLap;
        this.recordLimit = recordLimit;
        this.recordTotalCount = recordTotalCount;
    }

    public String getRecordTitle() {
        return recordTitle;
    }

    public void setRecordTitle(String recordTitle) {
        this.recordTitle = recordTitle;
    }

    public int getRecordCount() {
        return recordCount;
    }

    public void setRecordCount(int recordCount) {
        this.recordCount = recordCount;
    }

    public int getRecordLap() {
        return recordLap;
    }

    public void setRecordLap(int recordLap) {
        this.recordLap = recordLap;
    }

    public int getRecordLimit() {
        return recordLimit;
    }

    public void setRecordLimit(int recordLimit) {
        this.recordLimit = recordLimit;
    }

    public int getRecordTotalCount() {
        return recordTotalCount;
    }

    public void setRecordTotalCount(int recordTotalCount) {
        this.recordTotalCount = recordTotalCount;
    }
}
```

**RecordAdapter Class.**

```
package com.example.coronatasbeeh;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class RecordAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecordAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    List<RecordModel> recordModels;
    Context context;


    public RecordAdapter(Context context, List<RecordModel> recordModels) {
        this.context = context;
        this.recordModels = recordModels;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.record_items, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


        RecordModel rm = recordModels.get(position);
        holder.recordTotalCount.setText(rm.getRecordTotalCount());
        Log.i("recordtotalA", "onBindViewHolder: " + rm.getRecordTotalCount());
        holder.recordCount.setText(rm.getRecordCount());
        Log.i("Rc", "onBindViewHolder: " + rm.getRecordCount());
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return recordModels.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView recordCount, recordLap, recordLimit, recordTotalCount, recordTitle;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            recordCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recordCount);
            recordLap = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recordLap);
            recordLimit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recordLimit);
            recordTotalCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recordTotalCount);
            recordTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recordTitle);


        }
    }
}
```

**RecordActivity Class**

```
package com.example.coronatasbeeh;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RecordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
Toolbar toolbar;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<RecordModel> recordModels =new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_record);
        recyclerView =  findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewRecord);
         toolbar = findViewById(R.id.RecordToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
     //   setTitle("Record");

        RecordAdapter recordAdapter = new RecordAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                recordModels);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recordAdapter);

       bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationBar);
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.record_bottomNav);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.home_bottomNav:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                        return  true;
                    case  R.id.record_bottomNav:
                        return  true;
                    case  R.id.setting_bottomNav:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SettingActivity.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                        return  true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

}
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.record_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id==R.id.info){
            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecordActivity.this);
            View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.record_info_dialog, null);
            Button btn_ok =mView.findViewById(R.id.btnOkRecordInfoDialog);
            alert.setView(mView);
            final  AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
            alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
            btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
        else  if (id==R.id.deleteAll) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Delete All", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return  true;
    }



    }
```

**activity_record.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bgMain">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/RecordToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/toolbarTextSize"
        app:title="Record"
        android:theme="@style/RecordActionBar"
        android:background="@color/toolbar"
        app:titleMarginStart="20dp"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
   />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewRecord"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RecordToolbar"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:itemBackground="@color/toolbar"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**record_items.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bgMain"
   >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RecordToolbar"
        android:elevation="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:padding="10dp"
            >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recordTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/recordDelete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"

                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recordCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/recordTitle"
                android:text="Count: 44"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recordLap"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/recordTitle"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/recordCount"
                android:text="Lap: 8"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recordLimit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/recordTitle"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/recordLap"
                android:text="Limit: 66"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recordTotalCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/recordTitle"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/recordLimit"
                android:text="Total Count: 572"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: recordsModel is empty

Comment: i told u i set its value from another class its not empty. i checked it from logi.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing an empty array to the adapter

here :

```
 List<RecordModel> recordModels =new ArrayList<>();
```

try to initialize the array with data before passing it to the adapter.

// before  `alertDialog.dismiss();` Line
// create the list

```
List<RecordModel> recordModels =new ArrayList<>();
```

//then add models you created to the the list

```
recordModels.add(recordModel)
```

//then  init adapter

```
RecordAdapter recordAdapter = new RecordAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                recordModels);
```

// finally set the adapter.

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(recordAdapter);
```

Comment: then what i can pass there? i want to fetch data of model class.

Comment: you can pass dummy data (Create an Array-list of RecordModel and init it with any data 
 before passing it to the adapter), or fetch data from a service and pass it the adapter.

Comment: but in RecordModel i set data from another class and on that class RecorModel class data works properly. now i just want to get that data of Record Model class in RecordAdapter class.

Comment: just check now,  i break main Activity class on that point when i set data for RecordModel

Comment: I saw it, you are doing nothing with the list you passed to the adapter it still empty.

Comment: then please correct it. i just want to get RecordModel data in RecordAdapter.

Comment: got this error... E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.coronatasbeeh, PID: 17970
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4b8